# how to add multiple app.config files to my unit test project

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

In my project I am reading a value from app.config. When I did unit test for the same by my sub unit test project, I have added app.config file to the test project. Now my requirement is to do unit test for my other sub project. I tried by adding app.config as a file as wel as link. Its giving an error as "item exists with the same name". How can I add multiple config files or is there any alternative way. I am using Visual studio 2012.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know you can have single file in main folder and more in sub folders.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  I dropped an app.config in my Test project with all the correct values.  There is a business rule that if the configuration is incorrect the user will get a friendly message telling them what item needed to be corrected.  I can't just keep changing app.config files between test methods since these all need to run automatically without user intervention.  How do I specify different app.config files for different methods

Answer (score 1):

I think , [Managing Multiple Configuration File Environments with Pre-Build Events](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ManagingMultipleConfigurationFileEnvironmentsWithPreBuildEvents.aspx) by 
Scott Hanselman is a good reference for you !

Comment: The above reference is giving options to choose while debug / release /deployment time. Actually my  whole team connected through TFS, for each and every sub project need to have their config files while doing unit test.How can I refer all config files of sub projects in Unit test project

Comment: I read the linked article.  this doesn't really address the issue that the SO user was making.  It just addresses having multiple configuration files for multiple deployment types, which was different than having multiple configuration files for the same project at runtime.